# Calculate volume of pit with geotools

Tags: geotiff-tiff, dem, java, geotools, volume

I have DEM data in .geotif file. I want to calculate volume of pits. In geotools library implemented geotiffreader on 28 version. Can I calculate?

Comment: extract perimeter of the pit and multiply by the depth of the pit? what have you tried so far? what is not working for you? We need to see the code and any error messages